# Why does defining my code cause it to work improperly when automating website logins?

Tags: python, html, web

I have a bit of code that works to automatically log someone into their outlook email in the chrome browser. The user would have to have their email and password inputted into the code for it to work. It works fine until I try to define the body of the code to make it cleaner and to allow for more code to be written underneath without it messing with the function.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

def outlook():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    x = 'https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=13&ct=1592499273&rver=7.0.6737.0&wp=MBI_SSL&wreply=https%3a%2f%2foutlook.live.com%2fmail%2f0%2finbox%3fRpsCsrfState%3d8a0340e9-f9ec-d8ca-1b7d-c36e5fc0520f%26wa%3dwsignin1.0%26nlp%3d1&id=292841&aadredir=1&CBCXT=out&lw=1&fl=dob%2cflname%2cwld&cobrandid=90015'
driver.get(x)

    loginBox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="i0116"]')
    loginBox.send_keys('email')

    loginButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="idSIButton9"]')
    loginButton.click()

    passBox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="i0118"]')
    passBox.send_keys('password')

    time.sleep(2)

    passButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="idSIButton9"]')
    passButton.click()

outlook()
```

The time.sleep function is because the button click doesn't register when the code runs too fast.
The issue is, the above code with the defined function works normally but closes the chrome window it creates after logging in. If I remove the 'outlook()' and the 'def outlook():' it works fine without closing the chrome window.

I am wondering why that is and if there is a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try pulling the webdriver instantiation out. I think it's getting garbage collected- that's the only thing that makes much sense.

edit: Also, driver.get(x) should be indented, I'm pretty sure. Also also, you may run into problems down the line with the driver getting stale. I would set things up as:

with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
    outlook()

(And remove the original driver=webdriver.Chrome() )

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
def outlook():
    x = 'https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=13&ct=1592499273&rver=7.0.6737.0&wp=MBI_SSL&wreply=https%3a%2f%2foutlook.live.com%2fmail%2f0%2finbox%3fRpsCsrfState%3d8a0340e9-f9ec-d8ca-1b7d-c36e5fc0520f%26wa%3dwsignin1.0%26nlp%3d1&id=292841&aadredir=1&CBCXT=out&lw=1&fl=dob%2cflname%2cwld&cobrandid=90015'
    driver.get(x)

    loginBox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="i0116"]')
    loginBox.send_keys('email')

    loginButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="idSIButton9"]')
    loginButton.click()

    passBox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="i0118"]')
    passBox.send_keys('password')

    time.sleep(2)

    passButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="idSIButton9"]')
    passButton.click()

outlook()
```

Comment: You're welcome! Oh wait there's another problem. You didn't indent 'driver.get(x)'. I'm a little surprised that it doesn't just throw an error?